# Maven/Java-how to specify which jar file to use

Tags: java, maven

I have feeling I will get down voted. Please pardon my ignorance on this subject as I need to get this working soon.

Basically, I have two dependencies.  Same GroupId, Same Version, but different artifactID.
There are duplicated Classes in these two artifacts, but one of them has some beta features.

How do I ensure part of my code use classes from Jar1, the rest of my code use classes from Jar2 ?

**My bad. There is no overlap. Sorry for all the confusion :-(**

Comment: I do not think that it is possible without some kind of classloader trickery and it is not going to be easy.

Comment: can you rename the package path in the beta jar? That would be the most straight-forward way to accomplish that but I don't know if you have control over the jars you're consuming. Something like com.foo => com.foo.beta or com.foo.v2 or whatever...

Comment: I think you should look for a better way to solve this problem. Could you not refactor the package name to indicate beta version.

Comment: it is a third-party package... I probably should ask on their mailing list.

Comment: @thinkanotherone - what third-party library? It's possible that there are different packagings that exclude the common classes. Otherwise, no, there's no way to work-around the problem from within Maven, but it shouldn't be too painful to write a script to repackage.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating two projects? One dependent on artifactID1 other other dependent on artifactID2. One project would then depend on the other project. This is predicated on all the code using one version of the jar not being dependent on code that uses the other version.